# Android-Volley : set HTTP Header for JsonArrayRequest

Tags: android, json, http-headers, android-volley

so I've seen a couple of examples for JsonObjectRequests where either this code has been added

```
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }
```

and sometimes this Code has been used

```
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }
```

either way, it has always been used in combination with a JsonObjectRequest. I don't really know where to add the `@Override` of the methods inside my JsonArrayRequest. This is how my JsonArrayRequest looks like

```
JsonArrayRequest localJReq = new JsonArrayRequest(localURL,
      new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response){
            try{
                for (int i=0; i < response.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = jsonObject.getString("Title");
                    data += "Beschreibung: "+title+"\n\n\n";
                }
                output.setText(data);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No more Items Available",
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
    });
```

I've tried to add it in `{}` just behind the last closing `)` but that didn't work. I tried putting it inside the `Response.Listener` which also didn't work. So I'm a little bit confused.

Anyways I think it is really strange that I am making a JsonArrayRequest but since my REST API is accepting HTML & JSON as a response, Volley seems to get the HTML response instead of the JSON. Which is leaving me with no items inside my App. Isn't that kind of weird ? Since it is a JsonRequest shouldn't the Request set the content-type to application/json by its self? I'm hoping that by setting the content-type to application/json that I will get the correct response type.

Comment: Try adding "Accept" header with "application/json" value inside getHeaders()

Comment: @BNK it WORKED!!! You are a lifesaver!!! I'm such an idiot, I put `Content-Type` and `application/json` inside the `getHeaders()` - when all I had to do was change it to `Accept` and `application/json`

The `@Override` has to follow the closing parenthesis and be inside curly braces, just like @bharat said in his Answer. Funny thing tho, the `getHeaders()` Override is enough, I deleted the `getBodyContentType()` Override. Thank You!!!

Comment: Content-Type for sending, Accept for receiving :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call those method at the end of the request and brefore`;`

```
    JsonArrayRequest localJReq = new JsonArrayRequest(localURL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
           }) {//here before semicolon ; and use { }.
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return super.getHeaders();
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return super.getBodyContentType();
        }
    };
```

Comment: that's odd. I actually have tried this but it didn't work.. My App still received the HTML response instead of the JSON response. That is why I'm trying in the first place...

Comment: it is important to point out that the `getHeaders()` must be changed to `headers.put("Accept, "application/json");`
The `getBodyContentType()` can be removed I guess.. 
Maybe you could Edit your Answer? and Add those lines for future references..